# I want to make webview in android, but back button function not work?

Tags: android, webview

i am making webview in android, i am begineer in android. Below my code and i am facing following problems.

1. Back button not work , when i visiting different pages of my application and press back button then its not work and give error application has been stoped and take back me on home screen of my mobile.
2. 2nd i want when any user open this application then if internet not connected or not working then its give the alert some like "This application required internet connection" and in background by default my given background show wihotu internet connection. If internet connection found then this app work fine.

I am new in android. In advance i am very thankful for this help. and please in your answere write the code for fix the below issues. Thanks in advance

```
package com.example.edarabia;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.view.KeyEvent;


@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView mywebview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.grafdom.com/operations/projects/ma/edarabiaapp/");        
    WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mywebview.canGoBack()) {
        mywebview.goBack();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}



}
```

Comment: webview is null because it is not affected anything.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should remove

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed (){
       if(webView.canGoBack()) webView.goBack();
       else super.onBackPressed();
   }
   ```

to avoid NullPointerException. Why do you use such implementation?
2. You can use such function for your purpose:

```
    public boolean isOnline() {
       boolean res = false;
       ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
       if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
           res= true;
       }
       else
       {
           Toast.makeText(context, "You've lost internet connection. Please check it and try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           res = false;
        }
       return res;
   }
```

and in the Activity:

```
boolean isOnline = isOnline();
if (isOnline)
 {
      //What you want to do if there's a connection..
  }
```

Comment: Can you show me full code for both point where add and which thing delete, i not understand where i add this boolean can you show me this is in my code how everything come and for point 1 what do for back button ? Now i am changing my code then eclispe show wrong line error symbol

Comment: tell me please what is the purpose of overriding onBackPressed ()?

Comment: you can put this function isOnline() in separate class, like FrequentlyUsedMethods. And then, in all yours Activities you create an instance of that class and call this method isOnline. if it returns true, then you can do what you want - there is a connection. If it returns false, then show a notification(for example Toast) that there is no connection...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following,

**1.Override the back button functionality**

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

**2.For checking internet connection at app startup put the following code inside onCreate()**

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            if (!info.isConnected()) {

                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Please check your wireless connection and try again.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            // if positive, fetch the articles in background
            else
                // Do your task...
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Please check your wireless connection and try again.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Can you show me full code for both point where add and which thing delete, i not understand where i add this boolean can you show me this is in my code how everything come and for point 1 what do for back button ? Now i am changing my code then eclispe show wrong line error symbol

Comment: @user1474083 : replace your onBackPressed () with boolean onKeyDown() of my answer.Then add the second snippet to onCreate() so that it can check for internet connectivity at app start up.

Comment: i make the edit my code but still same problem with back button not working still, i use the your given code

Comment: you also show me the edit full code from start with internet problem solution

Answer (score 0):

You have not initalized the main `WebView webView;` and you are referring that in your `onBackPressed()` method thats why its giving you error.

Just change as below in your file:

> ```
> public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>     WebView mywebview;   <<--- instead of webview use mywebview which you have declared in your onCreate.
>    @Override
>   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>      mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
>      mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.grafdom.com/operations/projects/ma/edarabiaapp/");        
>      WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
>      webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
>      webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
>      mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
>  }
>  @Override
>  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
>      return true;
>  }
>  @Override
>  public void onBackPressed (){
>  if(mywebview.canGoBack()) mywebview.goBack();
>     else super.onBackPressed();  
>  }
>  }
> ```

For your second query:

You can check your internet connection using the below method:

> ```
>  public static boolean IsNetConnected()
> {
>     boolean m_netConnected = false;
>     try
>     {
>         ConnectivityManager m_connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) AppConstants.m_context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
>         if (m_connectivity == null)
>         {
>             Log.w(TAG, "couldn't get connectivity manager");
>             m_netConnected = false;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             NetworkInfo[] m_info = m_connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
>             if (m_info != null)
>             {
>                 for (int i = 0; i < m_info.length; i++)
>                 {
>                     if (m_info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
>                     {
>                         m_netConnected = true;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     catch (Throwable e)
>     {
>         ErrorReporter.getInstance().handleException(e);
>         if (AppConstants.DEBUG)
>         {
>             Log.e(TAG, "IsNetConnected Error" + e.toString(), e);
>             }
>         m_netConnected = false;
>     }
>     return m_netConnected;
> }
> ```

You can use the above method as below :

> ```
>   if(!IsNetConnected())
>     {
>    showDialog(MainActivity.this,"This application required internet connection");
>      //set your default background as per your requirements.
>    }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

override the functionality of **onBackPressed()**

```
@Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
      finish();
  }
```

hope this will help you.