# Android and java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu

The Back button on android application doesn't work in android 2.3 and developing an application on eclipse and ubuntu system, My emulator also doesn't have an back button enabled, I can't figure out what is not working as even when create an apk and install my mobile it doesn't works ? please help me with this issue.

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView myWebView;



    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        //myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");

        //WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        //setting JS to work in html pages in app
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //myWebView.setInitialScale(50);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/testhtml5.html");
        //mWebView.loadUrl("http://beta.html5test.com/");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358590/i-want-to-make-webview-in-android-but-back-button-function-not-work?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(mWebView.canGoBack() == true){
                    mWebView.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Edit:

put this statement:

```
WebView myWebView;
```

inside of your Activity before the onCreate() method and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add custom functionality to the back button you need to override the OnBackPressed in your activity. Like this:

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
   //your custom actions
 }
```